# Помогите с ЮKassa для телеграм бота C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Делаю телграм бота на C# с подключением платежей через тестовый токен ЮKassa, отправляю запрос, оплата в самом чате отображается успешно, но бот падает с NullRefernceExeprion, отдебажил update.Messege равне Null, не понимаю, не отвечает ЮKassa или же сам телеграм?

Отправка оплаты:

```
private static async void SendPayment(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await botClient.SendInvoiceAsync(chatId: update.Message.Chat.Id,
                title: _gameToBuy.Name,
                description: _gameToBuy.Desciption,
                payload: "somePayload",
                providerToken: _paymentToken,
                currency: "RUB",
                prices: new List<LabeledPrice>() {new LabeledPrice("Aboba", 500 * 100) },
                startParameter: "exapmle",
                isFlexible: false
            );
        }
```

```
Проврка оплаты:

case UpdateType.PreCheckoutQuery:
                    {
                        CheckPayment(botClient, update, cancellationToken);
                        return;
                        
                    }
```

Метод проверки:

```
        {
            PreCheckoutQuery preCheckout = update.PreCheckoutQuery;
            if (preCheckout != null)
            {
                await botClient.AnswerPreCheckoutQueryAsync(update.PreCheckoutQuery.Id, cancellationToken);
                SuccessfulPayment successfulPayment = update.Message?.SuccessfulPayment;
                if (successfulPayment != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Оплата прошла");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: На этот влпрос лучше всего ответит отладка кода. С пониманием, что такое `NullReferenceException` вопросов нет?